# Zoom text on html load and fade out at different location on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is for HTML website with CSS and Javascript.

I am trying my best to archive the below, but i am not getting what is required.

This is for the logo which is a text, which will zoom in and out when the page loads and then it goes and sits in its place.

Example:
1. On page load, the text "Hello" zoom size 200% starts from top corner heading towards center of the page
2. Page load continues - say 50% of page load, the zoom of the text heading toward center is 500%
3. Page load completes - the text "hello" has come to center with zoom 800%
4. Pause for 3 seconds
5. Zooms out to 500% heading towards left top corner (logo position)
6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner (logo position)
7. Fades out when reaching the logo
8. Logo appears

HTML Div:

```
<div id="hello">
<h1 style="zoom: 200%; transition: zoom 1s ease-in-out;">hello </h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function pageFullyLoaded()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("hello");
    elem.style.zoom = "500%";
}
```

Comment: `html` not appear to have element having `id` `"hello"` ?

Comment: missed it... is there something like what i am expecting possible for TEXT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `.animate()`

```js
// 3. Page load completes - the text "hello",
// has come to center with zoom 800%
$("#hello").animate({
  zoom: "800%",
  left: window.innerWidth / 2
}, 3000, function() {
  // 4. Pause for 3 seconds
  $(this).delay(3000)
  // 6. zooms out to 200% heading towards left top corner,
  // (logo position) 
  // 7. Fades out when reaching the logo 8. Logo appears
  .animate({
    zoom: "200%",
    left:0
  }, 3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  <h1 style="zoom: 200%; transition: zoom 1s ease-in-out;">hello </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful, this works exactly like i wanted. perfect... i have a additional question. When the "hello" is going towards left corner, can it fade the texts "ello" and just take alphabet "H" towards the logo ?

Comment: @JohnFranky _"When the "hello" is going towards left corner, can it fade the texts "ello" and just take alphabet "H" towards the logo ?"_ Yes. At last `.animate()` try utilizing `start` function of `.animate()` to set `#hello` `html` to `"H"` before `<span>ello</span>` , call `.fadeOut(3000)` on `#hello span`

Comment: i tried to add <span>ello</span> and .fadeOut(3000) i am getting noting.. i think i am doing something wrong.. can tell me where exactly to add this to Hide "ello" and only take "H" ?

Comment: @JohnFranky Can post jsfiddle of _"tried to add <span>ello</span> and .fadeOut(3000)"_ ?